# Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to JSON_TABLE

Tags: json, mysql-workbench

I'm working with JSON tables and I'm running into an issue.  I get the following error:

Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to JSON_TABLE

I'm using MySQL Engine version 8.0.20 on AWS with MySQL Workbench

When I use the JSON_Table command directly off of my table (sf.purchases), I am able to get the expected JSON output.  For instance this works:

```
SELECT pur.*, jt.*
FROM sf.purchases AS pur,
JSON_TABLE (pur.items, '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS (
            C_jt_id FOR ORDINALITY,
            C_jt_item_uid VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.item_uid',
            C_jt_item_name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.name',
            C_jt_qty INT PATH '$.qty',
            C_jt_price DOUBLE PATH '$.price')
        ) AS jt;
```

An it converts
'[{"qty": "1", "name": "Test", "price": "59.99", "item_uid": "320-000002"}]'

into its respective columns.

However, when I create a VIEW I can't get JSON_TABLE to work on the resulting table

Here is the VIEW I create:

```
CREATE VIEW sf.lp AS
    (SELECT * FROM sf.purchases);
```

Here is the code that does NOT work

```
SELECT pur.*, jt.*
FROM sf.lp AS pur,
JSON_TABLE (pur.items, '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS (
            C_jt_id FOR ORDINALITY,
            C_jt_item_uid VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.item_uid',
            C_jt_item_name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.name',
            C_jt_qty INT PATH '$.qty',
            C_jt_price DOUBLE PATH '$.price')
        ) AS jt;
```

The RESPONSE is:  Error Code: 1210. Incorrect arguments to JSON_TABLE

I've checked the following:

- I've reduced the COLUMNs to see if that affects anything
- I've checked the dataset to see if any weird characters were somehow introduced
- The two tables and the Columns and Datatypes are identical.  Most importantly, `items` is of type JSON if both the TABLE (sf.purchases) and the VIEW (sf.lp)
- Both the TABLE and VIEW use Character Set latin 1 and Collation latin1-swedish_ci
- I've run JSON_STORAGE_SIZE to verify that items in the table adhere to the JSON format

```
SELECT pur.items,  
JSON_STORAGE_SIZE(pur.items)
FROM sf.lp pur
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Through hours of trial and error I found out that apparently you need a GROUP BY to make the VIEW work in such a way that the JSON_TABLE does not throw the error.  This seems to work but I'm not sure why.  

CREATE VIEW sf.lp AS
    (SELECT * FROM test.purchases pur
GROUP BY pur.purchase_id); 

In my case the GROUP BY did not reduce the number of rows.

With further testing, it doesn't seem to matter why I GROUP BY but you must have that line.  Comments or explanations would be welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I think you were sad regarding no one replied your question, so, I decided to come back and help other people.

I have struggled with this problem and figured out why sometimes JSON_TABLE doesn't understand the source JSON.

In my case, I was sending another select result JSON field to CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE and getting this error.

I thought the MySQL was not recognizing the resulting field as json, so, I used JSON_EXTRACT over the resulting field to "force" this recognition inside the JSON_TABLE statement.

It is like:

`... CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_FIELD->'$[*]', COLUMNS ...)`

I hope to help somebody :)

Comment: This solved my problem (mysql Incorrect arguments to JSON_TABLE from "CTE"). Should be marked as accepted.

Comment: I think it's a bit better to use `JSON_TABLE(JSON_FIELD->'$', COLUMNS ...)` (`$` instead of `$[*]`)

Comment: @TheOnin thank you for you reply. In my case, when I wrote this reply, I was using an Array return, this is why I put "$[*]", so, I'm glad that you understood the point :)

Comment: why not just use `cast(JSON_FIELD as json)`